# How to set environment variable as docker image name on build

Tags: bash, command-line, docker, circleci

When using the file `circle.yml` file to build a docker image I'm trying to pass an environment variable `$CIRCLE_PROJECT_USERNAME` so that the file is less project specific. Unfortunately Docker build with the tag argument `-t` fails with:

```
docker build -t CIRCLE_PROJECT_USERNAME/$CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME:$CIRCLE_BRANCH . returned exit code 1

repository name component must match "[a-z0-9]+(?:[._-][a-z0-9]+)*" Action failed: docker build -t CIRCLE_PROJECT_USERNAME/$CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME:$CIRCLE_BRANCH .
```

**`Circle.yml` file:**

```
machine:
  environment:
  services:
    - docker

dependencies:
  override:
    - docker info
    - docker build -t CIRCLE_PROJECT_USERNAME/$CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME:$CIRCLE_BRANCH .

test:
  override:
    - docker run -d $CIRCLE_PROJECT_USERNAME/$CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME:$CIRCLE_BRANCH

deployment:
  hub:
    branch: master
    commands:
      - docker login -e $DOCKER_EMAIL -u $DOCKER_USER -p $DOCKER_PASSWORD
      - docker push $CIRCLE_PROJECT_USERNAME/$CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME:$CIRCLE_BRANCH

deployment:
  hub:
    branch: develop
    commands:
      - docker login -e $DOCKER_EMAIL -u $DOCKER_USER -p $DOCKER_PASSWORD
      - docker push $CIRCLE_PROJECT_USERNAME/$CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME:$CIRCLE_BRANCH
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should work, check if the env are actually set and only contain allowed characters:

```
[a-z0-9]+(?:[._-][a-z0-9]+)*
```

Edit:

```
docker build -t CIRCLE_PROJECT_USERNAME ...
```

Maybe just missing a `$` here? ;)

Comment: The build can be found [here](https://circleci.com/gh/ncrmro/meatier/2)

I've tried with and without the $

This is present when I printenv

CIRCLE_PROJECT_USERNAME=ncrmro

Comment: Yeah, you are missing a `$`, try `docker build -t $CIRCLE_PROJECT_USERNAME/$CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME:$CIRCLE_BRANCH`

Comment: @ErikDannenberg I concur. +1

Comment: Hmm actually working now, must have had a typo or something along the way, thanks!